# ASP.NET control property with [Flags] enum

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I have developed an ASP.NET control for which one of the properties is a [Flags] enum. However, I don't seem to be able to specify multiple flags for this property in the ASP.NET control markup. Is there a special syntax to do this or is it just not possible?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Maybe I'm understanding the question wrong, but can't you set the enum value with a comma-separated string.

E.g. if I have this property in my control:

```
public System.IO.FileOptions Options { get; set; }
```

The I can set it in the markup like this:

```
<uc1:MyControl ID="control1" runat="server"
    Options="DeleteOnClose,Asynchronous" />
```

Answer (score 7):

Just seperate the flags by commas.

Test.ascx

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Test.ascx.cs" Inherits="Test" %>
<asp:Label ID="lblTest" runat="server"></asp:Label>
```

Test.ascx.cs

```
public partial class Test : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    public TestEnum MyProperty
    {
        //coalesce was done to be lazy. sorry. haha.
        get { return (TestEnum)(ViewState["te"] ?? TestEnum.One); }
        set { ViewState["te"] = value; }
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblTest.Text = MyProperty.ToString();
    }
}

[Flags]
public enum TestEnum : int
{
    One = 1,
    Two = 2,
    Four = 4,
    Eight = 8
}
```

Test.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Test.aspx.cs" Inherits="Test" %>

<%@ Register Src="~/Test.ascx" TagPrefix="test" TagName="Test" %>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <test:Test ID="test" runat="server" MyProperty="Four,Eight" />
</form>
```